# Change Default Azure Subscription for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-subscription

I work at a company that has plenty of Azure subscriptions. In Visual Studio, it appears that my 'DefaultAzureSubscription' will not change (or I just dont know how to do it).

For example, I use the below method to initialize my subscription that I want to work in:

```cs
    public async Task CreateCommonClient()
    {
       ArmClient = GetArmClient();
       Subscription = await ArmClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
    }
```

It always defaults to subscription that I do not want to work in.

Does anyone know how to change VS default subscriptions? Please and thank you!

Comment: Yes please that would be great. Ive been trying to change it using the command line but it does not persist over to Visual Studio.

Comment: The subscription which you are looking for is in same Azure account? And we can configure tenant ID instead of subscription ID.

Comment: For me, the different subscriptions are within the same tenant. Changing tenant does nothing to change subscription. I cannot seem to change my default subscription within visual studio (not vs code).

Answer (score 0):

To change default subscriptions in Visual Studio, I could be able to achieve it using `AzureCloudBash` in Vs code terminal.

```
az account subscription enable --subscription-id "<subscriptionID>"
```

***Or***

```
 az account set --subscription "<subscriptionID>"
```

**Note**: *The* `az account set` *command does not allow you to switch your active subscription to a subscription in a different tenant. To continue, you must first log in as a user within the desired tenant. You will get the following problem if you attempt to set your subscription to a subscription in a different tenant:*

[Refer MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-azure-subscriptions-azure-cli#change-the-active-subscription)

*When I tried in my environment before logging in, I got the same result:*

[image]

*A tenant must have complete control over all active subscriptions in order to change an active subscription. I would suggest you to use the following command and execute it by changing tenant.*

```
az login --tenant "<TenantID>"
```

[image]

*You can obtain the active tenant list by using the below command: (if needed)*

[image]

Reference:
[`az account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/subscription?source=recommendations&view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-subscription-cancel-examples)

***As an alternative, we can choose subscriptions using the command palette, as I suggested in a comment:***

Path:
"*view -> commandPalette -> Azure: Select Subscriptions*" (`ctrl+shift+p`)
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me in Visual Studio. The alternative suggestions is also obviously for VS Code, so not applicable.